# How to show message if filter returns empty array?

Tags: angular

I use pipe filter:

```
<tr *ngFor="let app of subDocuments | filter: filter; let i = index"></tr>
```

When pipe filter returns empty array this does not work:

```
 <tr *ngIf="subDocuments.length == 0">No data</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could certainly do as mentioned in [@StPaulis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64370805/6513921), it would incur calling the pipe twice. And based on the type of your pipe (a filter), it could mean iterating through a set of data twice.

To avoid it you could remove the pipe in the template, import it in the controller, provide it, inject it and use it with a member variable.

Try the following

Contoller

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FilterPipe } from "./pipes/filter.pipe";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: [ "./app.component.css" ],
  providers: [ FilterPipe ] // <-- provide it to the component
})
export class AppComponent {
  filteredSubDocs = [];

  constructor(private filterPipe: FilterPipe) { } // <-- inject it

  filterSubDocs() {
    this.filteredSubDocs = this.filterPipe.transform(this.subDocuments, this.filter);
  }
}
```

Now you could bind the `filterInput()` function as an event handler to the element that sets the `this.filter` variable. For eg. an input field

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filter" (ngModelChange)="filterSubDocs()" placeholder="search">
```

Now you could iterate over the `filteredSubDocs` variable in the template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="filteredSubDocs.length>0; else noSubDocs">
  <tr *ngFor="let app of subDocuments | filter: filter; let i = index"></tr>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #noSubDocs>
  <tr>No data</tr>
<ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<tr *ngIf="!(subDocuments | filter: filter)?.length">No data</tr>
```